# How to autologin in Office-365 in PowerShell script hosted in Task Scheduler

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, pnp-powershell

I created PowerShell script that runs well in PowerShell-ISE. It autologin with credential popup and works as expected.

Problem: While same script I added to Task Scheduler then it prompts credential and wait until select the user, once user select manually then it works as expected. But I want autologin and execute without prompt credential.

Command: Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com" -UseWebLogin
Note: Only -UseWebLogin option is applicable.
Area: Office365, SharePoint Online

Answer (score 0):

The best way around this is to use credential manager.  See this Blog [PNP and Cred Manager](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2017/08/12/using-the-windows-credentials-manager-with-pnp-powershell/)

The basics are that you add a credential to the credential manager on the server that is running this task, then in your PNP script you connect like this: note that "Admin" is the name that you give the credential when you create it.

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/AwesomeSite" -Credentials:Admin

Comment: When use -Credential at that time it throws error : "Connecct-PnpOnline : The sign-in name or password doesn ot match one in the Microsoft account system." Even Username and password correct then after it throws same error.